# How to avoid overlapping of div elements during draggable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using around 8-10 div elements..all are resizable and draggable.. now i want to avoid overlapping of each element on other during resizable or draggable..how i can i do that? I feel javascript,html,css, jquery code for me is more helpful..pls help me...part of the code for 2 elements will be like this...

```
<!--Reizable and draggable for the HEADER widget**************-->
$(function() {
        $( "#placeLabel" ).draggable();
        $( "#placeLabel" ).resizable({
                ghost: true,
                handles: "n, e, s, w"

                                  });
    });

<!--Reizable and draggable for the TWITTER widget**************-->
$(function() {
        $( "#twitterLabel" ).draggable();
        $( "#twitterLabel" ).resizable({
            ghost: true,
            alsoResize: '#twt',
            alsoResize: '#tweets',
                handles: "n, e, s, w"
                                  });
    });
```

Comment: a combination of margins and clears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like z-index in css could help you out, but I'm not sure if that works in this case since I don't have any experience with draggables.

```
z-index:1; /* for the bottom div */
z-index:100; /* for the top div */
```

Have a try and see if it work.

Comment: can we use your z-index idea for more than 2 div's? here i have shown only 2 div's..but i have around 10 div's of these types

Comment: It depends, if the the divs have the same class or id, it won't work. But if they each have an unique class/id it will probably work.

Comment: thats a bit misleading you can if z-index, is different using, the style attr... and yes you can have a max `16777271` or more different layers (depends on browser) http://www.puidokas.com/max-z-index/ explains it better